# javascript what kind of data is this?

Tags: javascript

Hi,

I had google developers tool to convert my flash movie into javascript. I am reading through the generated code and I found all the images were converted into data:base64. That I get it but there are some other parts of the code that look like this:

```
{"data":":360c480Hb80D:00H20cb20C20c20C00hb:80d20c00hb20c20c00h20cb80d:00h20Cb20c20C20c00Hb:80D20C00Hb20C20C00H20Cc:800f:b80D:00H20cb20C20c20C00hb:80d20c00hb20c20c00h20cb80d:00h20Cb20c20C20c00Hb:80D20C00Hb20C20C00H20Cc:800f:b80D:00H20cb20C20c20C00hb:80d20c00hb20c20c00h20cb80d:00h20Cb20c20C20c00Hb:80D20C00Hb20C20C00H20Cc","unicode":"\u2026","advance":18400}
```

What kind of data is this and how can I see the way it actually looks like? I tried by pasting it on the address bar of my browser but no use.

Thank you.

I am adding a bit larger context to the code so it is more understandable:

```
tags":[{"data":"images/girl.jpe","width":800,"id":1,"type":8,"height":300},{"paths":[{"data":["#40"],"fill":0}],"flat":true,"bounds":"#28","fillstyles":[{"transform":"#17","bitmap":1,"type":6}],"id":2,"type":1},{"depth":1,"id":2,"colortransform":"#30","type":3,"matrix":"192H::193H::"},{"type":2},{"depth":1,"replace":true,"colortransform":"#62","type":3,"matrix":"192H::193H:N"},{"type":2},{"depth":1,"replace":true,"colortransform":"#92","type":3,"matrix":"192H::193H:8B"},{"type":2},{"depth":1,"replace":true,"colortransform":"#41","type":3,"matrix":"192H::193H:1D"},{"type":2},{"depth":1,"replace":true,"colortransform":"#76","type":3,"matrix":"192H::193H:5E"},{"type":2},{"depth":1,"replace":true,"colortransform":"#73","type":3,"matrix":"192H::193H:9F"},{"type":2},{"depth":1,"replace":true,"colortransform":"#114","type":3,"matrix":"192H::193H:3H"},{"data":"images/top/banner/flowers.jpe","width":45,"id":3,"type":8,"height":49,"mask":"images/top/banner/flowersfaded.png"},{"paths":[{"data":[":jCa:80ia00i:a:80Ic"],"fill":0}],"flat":true,"bounds":"jC00i80i","fillstyles":[{"transform":"45184l::45184ljC","bitmap":3,"type":6}],"id":4,"type":1},{"depth":2,"id":4,"colortransform":"#18","type":3,"matrix":"192H::192H107i60w"},{"depth":3,"id":4,"colortransform":"#18","type":3,"matrix":"192H::192H501i31s"},{"depth":4,"id":4,"colortransform":"#18","type":3,"matrix":"192H::192H521h63w"},{"depth":5,"id":4,"colortransform":"#18","type":3,"matrix":"192H::192H906h60r"},{"descent":2036,"ascent":16800,"emSquareSize":20480,"name":"MS Mincho","glyphs":[{"data":":360c480Hb80D:00H20cb20C20c20C00hb:80d20c00hb20c20c00h20cb80d:00h20Cb20c20C20c00Hb:80D20C00Hb20C20C00H20Cc:800f:b80D:00H20cb20C20c20C00hb:80d20c00hb20c20c00h20cb80d:00h20Cb20c20C20c00Hb:80D20C00Hb20C20C00H20Cc:800f:b80D:00H20cb20C20c20C00hb:80d20c00hb20c20c00h20cb80d:00h20Cb20c20C20c00Hb:80D20C00Hb20C20C00H20Cc","unicode":"\u2026","advance":18400},{"data":"","unicode":"　","advance":5120},{"data":":80t720Bb80D:0H20cb40n80l20s80tb40f20k40j40rb0x80d40f80db0x:80d0Xb20c20C20c00Hb:20G20G40Nb80P80P600C40Vc","unicode":"、","advance":7141.818181818182}
```

Comment: Looking at the data, it consists of a header `360c480Hb80D` and then 4 different patterns: `00H20cb20C20c20C00hb` , `80d20c00hb20c20c00h20cb80d`, `00h20Cb20c20C20c00Hb` and `80D20C00Hb20C20C00H20Cc` which get repeated. Thus i'm not sure what kind of data this could be. Maybe you can link some more code in context?

Comment: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2005/06/15/py-xml.html
maybe it can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Based purely on the context:

```
{
  "descent": 2036,
  "ascent": 16800,
  "emSquareSize": 20480,
  "name": "MS Mincho",
  "glyphs": [
    {
      "data": ":360c480Hb80D:00H20cb20C20c20C00hb:80d20c00hb20c20c00h20cb80d:00h20Cb20c20C20c00Hb:80D20C00Hb20C20C00H20Cc:800f:b80D:00H20cb20C20c20C00hb:80d20c00hb20c20c00h20cb80d:00h20Cb20c20C20c00Hb:80D20C00Hb20C20C00H20Cc:800f:b80D:00H20cb20C20c20C00hb:80d20c00hb20c20c00h20cb80d:00h20Cb20c20C20c00Hb:80D20C00Hb20C20C00H20Cc",
      "unicode": "\u2026",
      "advance": 18400
    },
    {
      "data": "",
      "unicode": "\u3000",
      "advance": 5120
    },
    {
      "data": ":80t720Bb80D:0H20cb40n80l20s80tb40f20k40j40rb0x80d40f80db0x:80d0Xb20c20C20c00Hb:20G20G40Nb80P80P600C40Vc",
      "unicode": "\u3001",
      "advance": 7141.8181818182
    }
  ]
}
```

I would say that it is defining the glyphs of 3 characters within a font called "MS Mincho". The hex values probably represent the path elements within the font glyph, although I don't recognize the encoding (which doesn't mean much - I don't know much about fonts).

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/glyph) for a description of how glyphs are encoded in SVG - you can see some similarities between the tags, but the path encoding is completely different.

Comment: Seems like all that code is an encoded Japanese character.